# Calculating the number of bound states in a finite 1-D potential well varying according to the depth of the well

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was told that for a *finite* potential well of depth $V_{0}$ and length(spread) $L$, the number of bound states($n$) that we could get for a particular $V_{0}$ is given by the equation- $$n=\left \lceil{\sqrt{8mV_{0}}L/h} \right \rceil$$How do I arrive at this point after looking at the graphs associated with the finite well problem? My guess is that we've to arrive at $n<\sqrt{8mV_{0}}L/h$, but I don't know how should I start so that I get a relation for the number of **bound states** in this problem. Can someone help me out in this, cuz I'm fairly new to QM!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60123/energies-and-numbers-of-bound-states-in-finite-potential-well?rq=1

Comment: Ok, but the expression I have, and the one used in your link are different!

Comment: Sorry but your $n$ is exactly the same as the $N$ in the linked answer.